# How to show nested data from viewbag in MVC Razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to implement Parent-Child Structure in MVC

[image: Like This]
i get both list from viewBag
so how to got nested structure in mvc Razor view
my html code here

```
  <table>
  @{  IEnumerable<SelectListItem> client = ViewBag.Client;
   foreach (var clientobj in client)
    {
     <tr>
       <th><label>@clientobj.Text</label></th>
          <td>
          <table class="list">
            @{                                                                IEnumerable<SelectListItem> project = ViewBag.Project;
            foreach (var projectobj in project)
          {
        <tr>
        <th><label>@projectobj.Text</label></th>
               <td>
          @Html.CheckBox("chk", projectobj.Selected, new { value = projectobj.Value })
              </td>
             </tr>
               }
           }
    </table>
        </td>

         </tr>}
            }

         </table>
```

my View Model is

```
public class ClientProjectViewModel
    {
        public int Clientid { get; set; }
        public string ClientName { get; set; }        
        public IEnumerable<ProjectViewModel> project { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What  problem are you having ?

Comment: @Shyju i got all child list but i want those child who matched with parent id so how to filter child according to parent id

Comment: How are they both connected ?

Comment: @Shyju via foreign key

Comment: I don't see that in your question ! Please include relevant information (which properties are connected)

Comment: @Shyju I included my view Model

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109592/discussion-between-kkzone-and-shyju).

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a view model, you might simply consider loading the correct data to a a list of that and use that to pass data to your view (instead of using ViewBag to pass data)

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
  var clientList =new List<ClientProjectViewModel> 
  //load clients and it's projects
  clientList.Add(new ClientProjectViewModel { Clientid=1, ClientName="A", 
                                 projects=new List<ProjectViewModel> {
                               new ProjectViewModel { Id=1, Title="ProjectforThisclien1"}
  };    
  return View(clientList)
}
```

And in your view, which is strongly typed to a List of `ClientProjectViewModel`.

```
@model List<ClientProjectViewModel>
@foreach (var client in Model)
{
  <p>@client.ClientName</p>
  @foreach(var project in client.projects)
  {
    <span>@project.Title</span>
  }
}
```

I hard coded one client with one project, But you may consider replacing it with data from your db.